# Correcting errors made by dictation on OS X

Tags: voice-dictation

I have been using OS X dictation for a while, it strikes me how incredibly inaccurate it is. It also does not seem to come with a mechanism for easily correcting errors. How can I correct the errors made by dictation, without resorting to using the keyboard?

Comment: We found that the built in dictation was horrible so we switched to [Dragon Naturally Speaking](https://www.nuance.com/dragon.html).  Yes, it costs money, but it was orders of magnitude better than what Apple supplied.

Comment: I just wonder if it performs better with some "accents" compared to others...

Comment: @Allan: unfortunately, Nuance discontinued Dragon for Mac on October 22, 2018, and the software is no longer maintained or available for purchase

Comment: @SolarMike: most dictation software works much worse for woman and for people speaking in anything that isn't the dominant accent, so, yeah, I'd expect its worse for me